# How to make a nested react router component load to a new page and not half-way down the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

I currently have a situation where I have my main parent routes/switch within my `App.js` file but within a route within the `App.js` file, I have another component that also has it's own `<Router>` with routes/switch setup that calls another component called `<MyJobComponent />`

The hierarchy of files that I have setup are as follows:

```
App.js - has route/path to the component <AllJobs />
  |
  |---> AllJobs.js - has nested route/path to the component <MyJobComponent />
           |
           |---> MyJobComponent.js - has the <Link to={`/my-job-id/${item.job_id}`}
```

It's here where this component is being rendered at the `AllJobs.js` level and not at the `App.js` level, which is where I would like it to be rendered.

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/job-path/:jobID" component={MyJobComponent} />
</Switch>
```

Within the `<MyJobComponent />` I have the following `Link to` code:

```
<TableCell style={{width: '10%'}}>
  <Link
     to={`/my-job-id/${item.job_id}`}
     style={{ textDecoration: 'underline', color: 'black' }}
  >             
    {item.job_id}
  </Link>
</TableCell>
```

Clicking on this `Link to` renders my page half way down the page within `<MyJobComponent />`

*****UPDATED based on react-router nested example*****

Looking at this example here: [React-Router Nested](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting) if you click on `Topics` and then click on the child link `Components` under Topics, you will see that it displays the heading `components` below these child links.

It is this section below the child links that I would like to display on it's own page, i.e. `components`. Is this possible?

Comment: It is really unclear, from the question you asked, what the problem is. If you want me to help I have to understand what is going on

Comment: @Delice - the problem is that within the `<MyJobComponent />` component, I have a column in a tablecell that is a `Link To` another component called `<MyJobComponentInfo />` that is part of a `Route exact path` situated within the `AllJobs.ls` component. With this in mind, when I click on the tablecell link to column within `<MyJobComponent />`, my actual `<MyJobComponentInfo />` is being rendered halfway down the page - basically at the `AllJobs.js` level and not from the top of the page. Something similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49404037/render-nested-route-component-on-new-page

Answer (score 0):

Move this to code to App.js:

```js
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/job-path/:jobID" component={MyJobComponent} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Tried what you have suggested here and unfortunately and move this route to `App.js` and now that actual `MyJobComponent` component is not being rendered at all. Basically nothing happens when I click the `Link To` column. Any ideas?

Comment: Also, I read other SO threads that mention this `There should be only one ROUTER in the whole app, which I think if your head file is App.js, then the ROUTER should wrap the whole App.js component` - I actually have a nested route that I am using within a material-ui tab system. Could this be causing me any issues with having more than one ROUTER?

Comment: included an actual example to reflect what my issue is exactly.