# Material-ui tablepagination default rows per page for various reports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, material-ui

I've been following an example with regards to material-ui `TablePagination` which they have as a `useTable` component and have the following code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Table, TableHead, TableRow, TableCell, makeStyles, TablePagination, TableSortLabel } from '@material-ui/core'

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    table: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
        '& thead th': {
            fontWeight: '800',
            backgroundColor: '#e0e0e0',
            color: '#000'                      
        },
        '& tbody td': {
            fontWeight: '500',
        },
        '& tbody tr:hover': {
            backgroundColor: '#bee8fd',
            cursor: 'pointer',
        },
        minWidth: 650
    },
}))

export default function useTable(records, filterFn) {

    const classes = useStyles();

    const pages = [5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100]
    const [page, setPage] = useState(0)
    const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(pages[page])
    const [order, setOrder] = useState()
    const [orderBy, setOrderBy] = useState()

    const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
        setPage(newPage);
    }

    const handleChangeRowsPerPage = event => {
        setRowsPerPage(parseInt(event.target.value, 10))
        setPage(0);
    }

    const TblPagination = () => (<TablePagination
        component="div"
        page={page}
        rowsPerPageOptions={pages}
        rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
        count={records.length}
        onChangePage={handleChangePage}
        onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
    />)

    const recordsAfterPagingAndSorting = () => {
        return stableSort(filterFn.fn(records), getComparator(order, orderBy))
            .slice(page * rowsPerPage, (page + 1) * rowsPerPage)
    }

    return {
        TblPagination,
        recordsAfterPagingAndSorting
    }
}
```

Within another component called `JobReport.js`, I import this `useTable` component as follows

```
import useTable from "./useTable";
```

and at the bottom of my report, I call the component `<TblPagination />` that is returned from `useTable.js`

My question is, at the moment within `useTable.js` the `rowsPerPage` is set to 5 based on state value. What I would like to be able to achieve is to provide this `useTable.js` component a dynamic value from any other component using it, to set that component's rowPerPage.

So within `ComponentA.js` I might have a report where I want to default the `rowPerPage` to 10 and in another component, I might default that report to 50 but both still calling the `useTable.js` component.

I thought I could pass this in as a prop to `<TblPagination page={3}/>` to return 50 but this didn't work.

With this setup, is there anyway I can set my rows to default to 50 within `<TblPagination />`

I am actually using useTable.js is a number of different components and want to be able to change the rowsPerPage to different values across these different components.

If I change it in `useTable.js` then all components calling it will have a default of 50 rows, which is not what I want.

Comment: how are you rendering the TblPagination in other components ?

Comment: @Shyam - as mentioned in my question - I just call the component `<TblPagination />` at the bottom of my report.

Comment: can you try calling it like this `{TblPagination(50)}`  and in your useTable hook you can access it as `const TblPagination = (rowsPerPage)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** give the ability to the component that uses this hook to define how many rowsPerPage. If not defined set default to 50.

```js
export default function useTable(records, filterFn, customRowsPerPage) {
  //..
  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(customRowsPerPage || 50)
  //..
}
```

---

Instead of:

```js
const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(pages[page])
```

Set default to 50:

```js
const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(50)
```

Comment: I realised this but I'm actually using `useTable.js` is a number of different components and want to be able to change the `rowsPerPage` to different values across these different components. If I change it in `useTable.js` then all components calling it will have a default of 50 rows, which is not what I want. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: *"My question is, at the moment within useTable.js the rowsPerPage is set to 5 based on state value. I actually want this report to default to rowsPerPage 50."* and so i guessed that was your issue. If your question is not setting default to 50 but having a more dynamic value for rowsPerPage then please edit your question.

Comment: I edited my answer. Please check if this is correct understood

Comment: Question has been edited to reflect exactly what I am after and that is a dynamic value for `rowsPerPage`

Comment: Your solution to give the component the ability to accept a dynamic value did the trick.

Comment: I have another question that I raised that I would appreciate if you could pls take a look as unfortunately not getting any responses. Hopefully you can assist or point me in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68769718/how-to-make-a-nested-react-router-component-load-to-a-new-page-and-not-half-way